# TVOS UITableViewCell _UIFloatingContentView what is it and for what?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, tvos

[image]

`_UIFloatingContentView`
What is it? How can i get rid of this and should i do that? It adding to the cell only after it been in focus. It's poorly documented.

Answer (score 1):

The underscore at the beginning of the class name means that this is a private class of Apple.

Because of its name, this class is probably defining some type of view that Apple uses to give a different appearance to the cells when they get the focus. But, unless you start working at Apple, or someday this class is made pubic in the SDK, you will never know for sure what it is this class for.

You should not deal with private elements. If they are not part of the public API, Apple is not expecting anybody to be using them. That means that they might decide to change its internal implementation, without any advice or deprecation period and all your code making assumptions about those private classes will be suddenly broken.